# How do I code multiplayer AR Game for my final year project?

Tags: arkit, arcore, multiplayer, sceneform, sceneview

So my professor suggested that I should create a multiplayer AR Game such that it involves one user to hit a ball which makes it change its position and then another player should be able to react to that change by hitting the ball from its updated position.

I believe ARCore Cloud Anchors could be the answer but I am so far have no clue how to proceed with that since there are little to no examples or tutorials available.

Any suggestion, help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

So far I have tried playing with AR SDKs such as Sceneforn (now depricated) and SceneView + ARCore. I have managed to place objects in the scene but I don't know how to make a session that another player sees that object placement too and further get its updated position.